# Change inside comments with Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, block-comment

Is there a way to change inside of a comment with Vim? I know you can change inside brackets and quotes with `i]` and `i"`. For example, If you are on a quote you can press,

> ci"my new textESC

And this will replace the text inside of the quote with the phrase "my new text", but how can I do the same thing with C comments which are enclosed with /* and */?

Comment: Maybe with the `%`? But you'd need to be at the start or the end of the comment.

Answer (score 5):

The Vim term for text that can be selected, yanked, deleted, and modified based on certain groupings of characters is *text object* (see [`:help text-objects`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects)). There's a comment-aware text object plugin called [textobj-comment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4570).