# Why does ci" (change inside quotes) not work in bash with vi mode enabled?

Tags: bash, vi, readline

My favourite way to use bash is with readline's vi mode, enabled with `set -o vi`. It works perfectly for me, except that `ci"` does nothing. The change inside X feature does not work.

What can I do to fix this? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

readline's vi-mode is a subset of **`vi`** (essentially features that affect a single line, with some allowances for usability).  The `ci` command is not part of **`vi`**; it is a **`vim`** feature.

Further reading:

- [A powerful VIM command I never knew about until now.](http://everythingsysadmin.com/2010/09/a-powerful-vim-command-i-never.html)
- [Vim 101: Efficient HTML Editing with Text Objects](http://usevim.com/2013/03/01/vim-101-text-objects-for-html/)
- [How to replace text between quotes in vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630440/how-to-replace-text-between-quotes-in-vi)
- [Change inside comments with Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154291/change-inside-comments-with-vim)